# Apache htaccess - modify query string with mod_rewrite

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I've recently changed scripting on my website, and this has resulted in a few 404 errors as some very old queries are no longer being redirected correctly.

I've been trying to create a rewrite rule to fix this, as it requires modifying the query string.

This is an example of a broken URI:

```
/index.php?/page/index.html/_/news/this-is-a-page-r34
```

If I can rewrite the query string as so, the request will succeed:

```
/index.php?/article.html/_/news/this-is-a-page-r34
```

So, with this in mind I have tried various rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file, but have not been having any success. Amongst a few other variations, I have tried the following:

**1st attempt**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)page/index.html(.*)$
RewriteRule /index.php /index.php?%1article.html%2 [L]
```

**2nd attempt**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/page/index.html/(.*)$
RewriteRule /index.php /index.php?/article.html/$1 [L]
```

**3rd attempt**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/page/index.html(.*)$
RewriteRule . /index.php?/article.html$1 [L]
```

It does appear to be matching the `RewriteCond`, so that's something, but the output never seems to get rewritten according to the `RewriteRule`.

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong? I think I've got to the point where I've been looking at it for too long and have become code blind.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `%1` (not `$1`) in your "2nd attempt" (as you did in your 1st attempt) and it looks like you should be *almost* there (see below for explanation):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/page/index\.html/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?/article.html/%1 [L]
```

If you're in `.htaccess` (or `<Directory>` section in server config) you need to also remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` pattern. (This is part of the directory-prefix that is *removed* in per-directory rewrites.)

Literal dots should also be escaped in regex, otherwise they match any character.

### `%1` vs `$1` back-reference

`%1` is a back-reference to the first parenthesised sub pattern (ie. captured group) in the last matched `RewriteCond` directive.

Whereas `$1` is a back-reference to the corresponding captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. *nothing* in this case!).